# matlab convhulln issue

Tags: matlab, convex-hull

Using matlab's "convhulln" (3D), my code sometimes crashes complaining of "initial facet 1 coplanar with the interior". This is correct when I inspect the shape of the object visually. But could I somehow check for this before using convhulln on the object, so I could avoid crash ? And find out which direction co-planarity lies in, so I could then use convhulln in a correct way ?

Comment: You have 13 questions and you accepted the answers to just 4 of them. This really does not help people being helpful to you.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I will try to be more responsive to the answers. But, what if the the answers are not the "answer" ? Should I accept and close the question?

Comment: I looked through your questions, and while they tend to be long winded and hard to read to find the real question, they often did have good answers. I'd go back and look at those answers. Be nice to the person who spent enough time to read your question and bother to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is not crashing the code, you can use the following structure:

```
try
   % Do your calculations
catch
   %This is evaluated if something went wrong
end
```